# Where do delayed bigquery events show up?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

This is regarding the automatically generated events and events_intraday dataset in bigquery. while messing around with an intraday table, i noticed that there are entries with event_timestamp from previous dates, which obviously means that some events that were logged on the device were not logged on the server at the same time. yet if i check any table from the events dataset, i see entries in created_at and event_timestamp (server log timestamp and device log timestamp respectively) of the same date only. how is this possible? shouldn't there be events that have a newer 'created_at' timestamp?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.

Comment: Some debug events appear in the intraday table but later they're not imported in the daily table. Nonetheless, I suggest reaching out directly to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to understand if these events you're seeing are being persisted somewehere after the intraday table gets deleted